# Installing JAR on Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I'm adding a resource by using **Build Path > Configure Build Path > Add External JAR**   my Android application throws an exception and says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ...`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Repeat N no of times ...

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Undo your "Configure Build Path" stuff

Step #2: Make sure that you are on the latest SDK tools and ADT plugin for Eclipse

Step #3: Create a `libs/` directory in the root of your project

Step #4: Copy your JAR into the `libs/` directory

Your JAR will be automatically added to your build path and its contents will be automatically added to your APK.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

- Remove all Android Library projects and external jars from the build
  path.
- Create a folder named 'libs' in your project.
- Place all external .jars in that folder, the ADT should now place
  them under 'Android Dependencies'.
- Re-import all your previous Android Library    projects the normal
  way.

The issue is that external jars are not placed in the 'libs' folder by default when using Properties - Java Build Path- Add External Jar, instead they are placed under 'Referenced Libraries' instead of 'Android Dependencies' and this causes the NoClassDefFoundError.

Please, [check Dealing with dependencies in Android projects for more details](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects)